# How some NoSQL DB (like MongoDB) can handle all of C and P in CAP theorem?

Tags: nosql, distributed-system

In any technologies article talk about CAP theorem ([example](https://gerardnico.com/data/distributed/cap)) , I get information:

> If a node of the system cannot talk to each other, If two node of the system cannot talk to each other, can they make forward progress on their own?
>
> If not, you sacrifice Availability
> If so, you might have to sacrifice Consistency.

My question is: How do system handle consistency( all nodes have the same data) if a node cann't talk to each other? Assumes there is updating a value on node A, how can node B has new data when node A and B cann't talk each other because of network failure?

Comment: If nodes can't talk to each other and you really want consistency, then you must abandon availability (stop serving requests until network is healed)

Comment: Yes, I know that database (MongoDB for example) have abandoned Availability to keep Consistency. But, my question is, How does MongoDB keep Consistency when a node can't talk to each other? Node A have new data but it can't talk to node B. I think their data are **not consistent** at that time.

Comment: With mongodb the trick is to not have replica sets that are evenly divisible in half. So if you have nodes A, B, C and C is separated from the replica set by a network failure, then it can't serve requests. But A and B can (they _are_ the set now). When network is healed and C rejoins the replica set, it'll catch up from replication log ("eventual consistency", it's called)

Comment: "Node A have new data" - no, it doesn't, because node A, being left alone, won't accept any writes (this is what "abandoning availability" means)

Comment: Oh, Your explanation seems to be perspicuous. Can you tell me which documents talk about it?

Comment: https://github.com/ept/blog/blob/master/src/_posts/2015-05-11-please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.md

https://gerardnico.com/data/database/newsql

According 2 article, will MongoDB return an error or a time-out while event of a network partition occurs(because MongoDB follows CP propeties)?